# Using Apply Map to Remove Unwanted Phrases from DF (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Right now, I have a DF like this

```
Words               Words1
Little Red         Red Apple
Cracker Barrel     Wood Grain
Far Away Man       Flat Rate Shipping
```

I want to remove cells from my DF based on a particular condition where certain words cannot appear together in the same phrase.

So for example: Remove cells from the following DF where "Flat" is in the same phrase as "Shipping" AND where "Far" is in the same phrase as "Man".  I've been playing around with something like this but it doesn't work...

```
Words.where(Words.applymap(lambda x: 'Flat' and 'Shipping' in x))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "remove cells"? I think you mean remove rows right? Then this will be an `apply` since you'll consider things rowwise.

```
In [8]: def pred(x):
    c1 = ('Far' in x[0]) and ('Man' in x[0])
    c2 = ('Flat' in x[1]) and ('Shipping' in x[1])
   ...:     return c1 and c2

In [9]: df.apply(pred, axis=1)
Out[9]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

So you can drop those rows that match your criteria with

```
In [10]: df[~df.apply(pred, axis=1)]
Out[10]: 
            Words      Words1
0      Little Red   Red Apple
1  Cracker Barrel  Wood Grain
```

It may be quicker to use the `str.match` method with a regex.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using Pandas and using this method throws the following error: IndexError: ('index out of bounds', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Figured out why it was throwing that error -- unfortunately this doesn't work for me

Comment: `DF = DF.applymap(lambda x: x if not '$' in str(x) else x.replace('$', ''))`   or   
`DF = DF.applymap(lambda x: x if not '%' in str(x) else x.replace('%', ''))`